# Execute image as php, Redirect to external site and return as image

Tags: php, image, magento, redirect, nginx

I am working on an image redirect for a fraud detection service in Magento.  The concept of the functionality is that the users hit the checkout page where an iframe is used to send a request to capture the data of the users device. Then an image is returned from the 3rd party service to show that the request and redirect was successful. And here is my issue:

I am using Nginx and php-fpm. The iframe which I described above works as designed. However there is a fallback for non-iframe support where a gif is used instead of an iframe to make the redirect. The gif is really a php file and I have configured Nginx and php-fpm to allow this one file to be executed as php. If i access the gif directly the redirect works fine but when put it as an image into the page I do not get the redirect as expected.

Here is the logo.gif file contents

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <?php
        $m = $_GET['m'];
        $s = $_GET['s'];
        header("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
        header('Content-Type: image/gif');
        header ("HTTP/1.1 302 Found");
        header ("Location: https://3rdpartysite.com/logo.htm?m=$m&s=$s");
        ?>
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you include the way in which the iframe and img fallback are included in checkout?

It may be worth noting that HTML 5 has removed support for iframe fallback which may be why the gif isn't being called at all: http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_iframe_tag.cfm

That piece aside, why not have PHP render the direct URL to the image rather than rely on a hop through logo.gif?  Or utilize javascript with a `<noscript>` fallback.

I don't believe that the logo.gif is the source of the problem as you've proven that it works correctly when directly visited.  The source of the problem lies in the implementation of the calling scope.

Comment: <iframe src="path/to/logo.htm"><img src="path/to/image/logo.gif"/></iframe>  I've taken the iframe out all together and just have <img src="path/to/image/logo.gif" /> just to try and get the gif to render properly.  I agree with why not just call it with php but the 3rd party software requires it do be done as so.

Comment: Does your path src start with a / or not?  My guess is you're getting a 404 for the gif because it's appending the path to the existing URL.  E.g. /checkout/cart/path/to/image/logo.gif

Comment: Good call on the html5 fallback though. The site is built in html5 and therefore I think this just isn't going to work how they want it to.

Comment: No sorry that was just for examples sake the fully qualified src path is "https://www.example.com/logo.gif"  - stackoverflow is trimming my https out but it is a secured request

Comment: Can you also paste in the contents of your console?  My suspicion is that the gif isn't being accessed at all.  Also, you should use the explicit protocol agnostic option when referencing resources via http|https: src="//example.com/logo.gif"

Comment: No errors in console. Image returns 302 found as it should and I can copy and paste the src url from inspecting the element in the browser into the url and it returns as expected. It just  for some reason wont render on the page. The url is an absolute path using https:// stacksoverflow trimmed that out for some reason in my previous comment

Comment: What's the style associated with the image?  Are we making this more complicated than we need to and the problem is something as simple as a display: none attribute or width/height 0px css issue?

Comment: No I get the  broken image icon. Im wondering if there is something going on with the firewall / load balancer not returning the redirect properly. But why would the iframe resolve just fine? IDK I'm stumped

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97697/discussion-between-evan-petersen-and-dofficial).